# Uncountable union of chain of subsets of R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, cardinals

For each $t \in R$, let $E_t$ be a subset of $R$. Suppose that if $s<t$ then $E_s$ is a proper subset of $E_t$.
$$\bigcup_{t\in R} E_t$$
Is countable.
How?

I see that the union runs over R which is an uncountable set.
Each of the set $E_t$ contains infinitely many subsets of R. It seems that this union equals R itself which is uncountable.  I Don't get how this union become countable??

Comment: Hint: there is a simple example where each $E_t$ is subset of $\mathbb Q$. (that assumes your question is "is it possible that union is countable"; it's not clear, what "Is countable. How?" means)

Comment: In methods of real analysis book by richard goldberg this is a problem which he answered that this union need not be uncountable. It means that this union may be countable under certain circumstances i want to know when.  Also if we consider $E_t$  as a subset of Q then how would you define the subset for an irrational t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple example. For each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, let $E_t = [0, t]\cap \mathbb{Q}$. From the density of rationals, we know that $E_s \subset E_t$ when $s < t$ and their union is countable since it's a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.